# Deploy a specific subfolder with cloud-run github action when working with a monorepo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions, google-cloud-run, monorepo

I am working with a mono repo and I would like to deploy my back-end (only) with the Cloud Run service (using the "official" [google cloud run action](https://github.com/google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun)). For this action, I need a Dockerfile at the root of my project for building my image. But my Dockerfile is under `./server`.

Is there a way to use something like `working-directory` for the `run` steps ? I didn't find anything from the doc.

Or do I have to have a Dockerfile at the root of my project and the Dockerfile points to the `./server`?

My project tree :

```
./
 .github/
   worflows/
     deploy-back.yml
  client/
    ...
  server/
    ...
    Dockerfile
```

```yaml
# deploy-back.yml
name: Deploy to production

# ...

jobs:
  deployment-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    environment: production
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
        uses: google-github-actions/auth@v0
        with:
          # ...
      - name: Deploy to Cloud Run
        uses: google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0
        with:
          service: ${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}
          source: gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
          project_id: ${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}
          region: ${{ env.RUN_REGION }}
          tag: ${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
```

Comment: There are many ways to specify the **working-directory** and at different levels in the GitHub Action. Example: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsrun

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are working on a monorepo and wants to run this particular workflow to deploy only when backend code base gets changed, I would start by limiting the trigger by only changes related to the `/server` folder.

```
on:
  push:
    paths:
    - 'server/**'
```

As for the Dockerfile location, I would keep under `/server` just because it's a monorepo. Now, to answer your question the Cloud Run GitHub actions you provided is expecting a parameter which points to your Docker image

```
source: gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
```

which means your Docker image has to be already built prior to run the "Deploy to Cloud Run" step. What I would do, add two Docker steps prior to the deployment so github actions can build the image:

```
- name: Docker auth
  run: gcloud auth configure-docker

- name: Docker build backend
  run: docker build -t gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }} . -f server/Dockerfile

- name: Docker push backend
  run: docker push gcr.io/${{ env.PROJECT_ID }}/${{ env.SERVICE_NAME }}:${{ env.PACKAGE_VERSION }}
```

Note the `-f server/Dockerfile` in the Docker build step which will point to the server folder and run the build from there or if you want (using bash) you can just change the directory during the build: `cd server/` then run the `docker build ...`

Comment: Finally I changed the "source" option of the "google-github-actions/deploy-cloudrun@v0" to be `source: ./server`, I missread the doc ^^